rotation components of an object relative to the camera
I'm displaying billboard quads in perspective projection, where I'm simulating 3d objects using spritesheets.
the individual frames in the sprite sheet are the object as seen from different perspectives:

In the quad vertex shader, I calculate an x/y offset into the spritesheet, based on the relative position of the object vs the camera. this is generally working well, but only as long as we assume both the camera and object UP is positive-y, and the object is rotated only about its y-axis. the roll information is missing. the 'R's here will always be upright:

I want to support full rotation of the object, where the relative latitude and longitude of the camera's view of the object is used in the look-up of the spritesheet, and the roll angle of the object relative to the eye-object ray is used to rotate the billboard accordingly.
what I have is a model matrix for the objects, and regular view and projection matrices for the camera. I can also have the rotations in quaternion form if that helps?
what I need is 3 angles that let me independently set the roll (billboard spin on the projection surface), pitch and yaw (spritesheet lookup) such that the object looks like it is rotated correctly.
float3 relative_position = shared.camera_position - object_world_position;
    
float y_rotation = atan2(-uniforms.rotation[2][0], uniforms.rotation[0][0]);
float h = (atan2(relative_position.z, relative_position.x) - M_PI_F / 2 ) + y_rotation;
float v = atan2(relative_position.y, sqrt(relative_position.x * relative_position.x + relative_position.z * relative_position.z));

h and v here are the horizontal and vertical offsets into the sprite sheet. I'm not sure if the roll component can be derived in a similar fashion..?
